# Ldap authentication in Loopback 4 -- 'Missing credentials'

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js, loopback4

I have followed the tutorials for adapting passport authentication strategies to Loopback 4, and have successfully gotten passport-http to work. But, when trying to get passport-ldapauth to work with loopback 4, I am consistently getting the following error Http response (using postman):

```
{
"error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "UnauthorizedError",
    "message": {
        "message": "Missing credentials"
    }
}
```

}

I have confirmed the online LDAP test server works with my setup (used a plain Express app with passport-ldapauth, with total success). Using the same LDAP config in Loopback 4, however, produces the above error.

My test Loopback app is here: https://replit.com/@woff2/CarefulGreenBits

It seems to me that I am doing something wrong with passing the verifyFn in to the AuthenticationStragegy.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have been at this for three or four days now!

It would be of great benefit to the community to solve this. I have seen many people online wanting the same auth method to work in Loopback over the past week.

UPDATE: I've narrowed it down to the request body not being processed. Whether the request body contains the username/password pair or not, the same 'Missing credentials' error results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the username/password tuple must be passed as params on the http request. This information was contained in source-code comments of the passport-ldapauth package. Note however that when using passport-ldapauth with Express framework, passing the tuple in the request body does work.